# Could not launch Failed to get the task for process -1 when running my WatchApp Target

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I am using Xcode 14.3.1. I have created new target for watch to work with my existing iOS app which is in swift. Created development and distribution provisioning profile and tried running. The app is getting installed in my watch (Series 8 , Version 9.1 (2OS75)) but its not getting launched and end up showing
**Could not launch
Failed to get the task for process -1.**

Tried the same certificates by creating sample project and tried running it worked perfectly

Created Developer and Distribution provisioning profiles
By going through some stack overflow answers tried disabling Debug executable

Comment: After a lot of trials I finally resolved the issue.

Select watch target >> Go to build settings >> Search for VALID_ARCHS , I  added **arm64_32** in user defined setting for **valid_archs** which successfully ran the application into the watch